# Qt Drag and Drop works in window. Can i make it so i can only drop into a Qlabel and not the entire window?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qlabel

Using Qt to create an application that accepts a file drop. I have an area on my UI that I want to drop the file into, using a `Qlabel`. I have the function of dragging and dropping the file into the UI working, however I can drop it anywhere on the window, and not just into the `Qlabel` area.

I thought using

```
ui->label_drag->setAcceptDrops(true);
```

would work, however this just removed the functionality all together. What is the best way of handling this? if possible at all.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a minimal and complete example?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to override the `QLabel` class. In the `dragEnterEvent` be sure to call `acceptProposedAction` to process the move and leave events. If you don't do that, only the `dragEnter` event will fire.

Sample code follows. To use this in your project, add the source to your project and then right click on the label on the form and promote the item to `QLabelDragDrop`.

```
#ifndef QLABELDRAGDROP_H
#define QLABELDRAGDROP_H

#include <QLabel>

class QLabelDragDrop : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QLabelDragDrop(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
protected:
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
    void dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event);
    void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // QLABELDRAGDROP_H
```

```
#include "qlabeldragdrop.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QDropEvent>

QLabelDragDrop::QLabelDragDrop(QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent)
{
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    setMouseTracking(true);
}

void QLabelDragDrop::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "dragEnterEvent";
    event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void QLabelDragDrop::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "dragLeaveEvent";
    releaseMouse();
}

void QLabelDragDrop::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "dragMoveEvent";
}

void QLabelDragDrop::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "dropEvent";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what i was looking for.